# Why is the App Clip Code payload size limit so small

Tags: apple-appclips

We're using App Clips and while it would be nice to use Apple's App Clip Codes, there seems to be an unusably small payload limit. Even trying to encode a relatively short URL such as the one below:

```
AppClipCodeGenerator generate --url 'https://www.example.com/1234567890ABCD' --index 8 --output ./appclip8.svg
```

returns the error:

```
Compressed URL too large: The compressed URL byte size exceeds supported payload size of the App Clip Code.
```

As a result the only way to encode anything useful is to have all parameters in a database with a reference in the URL, but this adds an additional round trip request to retrieve that data. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/creating_app_clip_codes/encoding_a_url_in_an_app_clip_code)

> An App Clip Code can only contain a limited amount of information, and
> as a result, the tools you use to create the code compress the encoded
> invocation URL. The underlying encoding algorithm can encode some
> words efficiently, while some characters may reduce the algorithm’s
> efficiency. As a result, the exact length of an invocation URL you can
> encode in an App Clip Code varies based on the ASCII characters and
> words you use.
>
> When you create an App Clip Code, both App Store Connect and the App
> Clip Code Generator command-line tool inform you if your invocation
> URL is too long.
>
> To ensure you can encode your invocation URL in an App Clip Code:
>
> Use the minimum number of characters you need to uniquely identify a
> resource. Long unique identifiers (UUIDs) lower the effectiveness of
> the encoding.
>
> Use a short host name with as few subdomains as possible.
>
> If possible, remove the www subdomain from your host name.
>
> Use decimal numbers as values for query components.
>
> Replace long query string argument names and values with short
> strings. For example, use https://example.com/?p=0 instead of
> https://example.com/?status=view.
>
> Omit a trailing slash (/) character at the end of the URL. For
> example, use https://example.com instead of https://example.com/.

Comment: can URL shortener be workaround?